# Normal, Non Separable field extension which is not Simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $p$ a prime ad $\mathbb{F}_p$ the finite field with $p$ Elements. In want to
understand why the field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y) \subset \mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p},Y^{1/p})$
isn't a simple extension. In other words why there no
$a \in \mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p},Y^{1/p})$ with $\mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p},Y^{1/p}) =
\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)(a)$.

Any ideas?

Motivation: that seems to be an example for a finite normal, non separable extension
which isn't simple.

Comment: Because $a^p\in\Bbb F_p(X,Y)$.

Comment: I think I understand you. $[\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y) : \mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p},Y^{1/p})]=p^2$, but $(\mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p},Y^{1/p}))^p \subset \mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)$. This lead us to contradiction?

Comment: Yes, you have an extension $L/K$ with $|L:K|=p^2$, but for each $a\in L$, $|K(a):K|\le p$.